# Target ID for XML Perspective

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an eclipse PDE plugin with multiple views. I want my views to be available only when the XML perspective is chosen. I know I can specify this by changing the target ID of the view in the plugin.xml file, but I cannot find the target ID for the XML perspective. **Does anyone know the target ID for the XML perspective?**

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
      <perspectiveExtension
            targetID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective">
         <view
               id="asher.views.id.SampleView"
               relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView"
               relationship="right"
               ratio="0.5">
         </view>
      </perspectiveExtension>
```

Comment: Note: you can always use 'Window > Show View' to show any view in any perspective, you can't restrict a view to a particular perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view will always be available in *every* perspective, but the ID you're looking for is "org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.perspective". You can find where it's declared at https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.sourceediting/blob/9a52e4d9b40b6340b0e2c72ee523bf603881cfb1/xml/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui/plugin.xml#L1489

Comment: What is the <perspectiveExtension> tag is used for since it doesn't restrict when the view will be available?

Comment: Exactly what https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_perspectiveExtensions.html?cp=2_1_1_195 says, it adds it to the layout when someone first opens or resets the perspective. You'll see it's referring to the view by ID, but it's not where you declared the view itself with the user-facing name and icon. Every view can be opened in any perspective the user chooses. I keep the Git Repositories and Staging views in my Java perspective. Is there something that makes your view only usable in that perspective?